# To implement a zookeeper system do I need to have zookeeper downloaded on every machine or just the master?

Tags: java, apache, apache-zookeeper

Do i need to download zookeeper on each system I'm trying to connect or just the master machine?

Comment: It should be noted that there is no primary in ZooKeeper. All ZooKeeper nodes can serve as the leader, and in order to account for failures you should provide more than one host:port when connecting to your ensemble.

Answer (score 1):

You need zookeeper running on each instance of the zookeeper cluster: a minimum of 3 machines if you're serious about this.

Comment: Do I need to make a zoo.cfg file in each or just the host?  Sorry I have a lot of questions; I'm pretty new to computer science.

Comment: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html. You really do need to read the manual. There's a quick-start guide for basic developer use as well.